# AWS - IAM and cleaning roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

My company asked my to clean every resources that is not used in our AWS organization account. I am currently removing users. roles and users groups.

Under the `role` page, there is `a Last Activity` section. if the last activity is `None` does it mean that the role was created but never used?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does mean that the `role` was not used.

But the more correct explanation would be this :- " single role is associated with single or more than one services.If it shows `none` that means that role didn't accessed any of the service associate with it.

if you want to find `one on one` basis that which services associated with this role was used when `simple click on the role name -> under summary -> go to access advisor` to see  services that the role can access and when those services were last accessed. Review this data to remove unused permissions.

[docs for reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_access-advisor-view-data.html#access_policies_access-advisor-viewing)